# Get highest index key of Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, key, max

How can I get the highest key in an array like that:

```
foo[0] == undefined
foo[1] == "bar"
foo[2] == undefined
foo[3] == undefined
foo[4] == "bar"
```

`foo.length` returns me 2, so if i iterate `foo.length` times, I'll never get the last value.

Or is there a way to count an array considering the undefined values as well?

Comment: might be better to figure out why the holes exist and manage a clean array. Are you using `delete`? Instead of `splice()`

Comment: The error was in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unsure why your code is not working, `.length` on an array like that shows 5 correctly in my example [here](https://repl.it/BKcs/1)
However, if you do not set values at all on specific indexes, you can do [this](https://repl.it/BKcs/4) :

```
var foo = [];
foo[1] = "bar";
foo[4] = "bar";

//grab existing indexes that have values assigned
var indexes = foo.map(function(val, idx) { return idx; });
//get the last one, this + 1 is your real length
var realLength = indexes[indexes.length - 1] + 1;
console.log("Real length: ", realLength);
//iterate using for loop
for(var i=0; i<realLength; i++) {
    var val = foo[i];
    console.log(i, val);
}
```

Comment: OP not trying to assign the values...is showing holes in array. That's why length is 2

Comment: I'm not using `==` to assign, I just gave an example that the value is equal (`==`) to. (comparing)

Comment: that's fair enough :)

Comment: try to just initialize the ones that have a value

Comment: Ah ok. Well this is understandable. According to ES5 array is essentially an Object with indexes implemented as integer properties. And as thus if you do not set a value on a specific index, this property does not exist, and so won't be iterated on.

Comment: I have added a possible solution, hope this helps :)

Comment: You saying that that you were not understanding why it was not working was the perfect answer, cause it made look to my code again, but this time with different eyes. I think the length was always correct but something made me think it was not. And thanks for the code too, maybe it can be of value some day ;)

Answer (score 1):

Highest Key

```
var index = foo.lastIndexOf(foo.slice(-1)[0]);
```